# how to convert algorithm from latex to word?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, msword

I have this algorithm steps I coded in LaTeX as follows:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Deep Q-Learning with Experience Replay}
    \label{alg:DQN}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \State Initialize replay memory $\mathcal{D}$ to capacity $N$
    \State Initialize action-value function $Q$ with two random sets of weights $\theta, \theta'$
    \For{$episode = 1,M$}
        \For{$t = 1,T$}
        \State
        Select a random action $a_t$ with probability $\varepsilon$.
        \State  
        Otherwise, select $a_t = {\arg\max}_a Q(s_t, a; \theta)$
        \State Execute action $a_t$, collect reward $r_{t+1}$ and observe next state $s_{t+1}$
        \State Store the transition $(s_t, a_t, r_{t+1}, s_{t+1})$ in $\mathcal{D}$
        \State Sample mini-batch of transitions $(s_j, a_j, r_{j+1}, s_{j+1})$ from $\mathcal{D}$
        \State Set $ y_j = \begin{cases} 
                    r_{j+1}, & \mbox{if } s_{j+1}\mbox{ is terminal} \\ 
                    r_{j+1} + \gamma \max_{a'} Q(s_{j+1}, a'; \theta'), & \mbox{otherwise}
                    \end{cases}$
        \State Perform a gradient descent step using targets $y_j$ with respect to the online parameters $\theta$
        \State Every $C$ steps, set $\theta' \leftarrow \theta$
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The output as follows:
[image]

Is there a way to convert this photo or algorithm to a word document without using an image of a latex document?
I tried to use insert equation in MS word but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you make a full `mwe`? I cannot compile your document without errors when I load just the `algorithmic` package.

Comment: For research papers to journals, if we submit the content in the journal format, it is OK. Final formatting will be done by the production department of the journal. As most of the journals accept latex submission, I don't see the need to convert to word format. You can type it in this case & use 'MathType' for the equations in the algorithm. Best wishes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a method I use often. (A 5 minute job)

(1) Prepare your LaTeX file with the content to be converted. In this example called `Test2WORD.tex`. You can use a system font that is already on your system. Here I am using `calibri`, the font I will be using in my main word document.

**File Test2WORD.tex**

```
%%% File Test2WORD.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}%

\usepackage{fontspec}   
\setmainfont{calibri} % a system font <<<<

\begin{document}
    
    Some text.

\begin{algorithm}   
        \caption{Deep Q-Learning with Experience Replay} \label{alg:DQN}
    \begin{algorithmic}
            \STATE Initialize replay memory $\mathcal{D}$ to capacity $N$
            \STATE Initialize action-value function $Q$ with two random sets of weights $\theta, \theta'$
            \FOR{$episode = 1,M$}
            \FOR{$t = 1,T$}
            \STATE
            Select a random action $a_t$ with probability $\varepsilon$.
            \STATE  
            Otherwise, select $a_t = {\arg\max}_a Q(s_t, a; \theta)$
            \STATE Execute action $a_t$, collect reward $r_{t+1}$ and observe next state $s_{t+1}$
            \STATE Store the transition $(s_t, a_t, r_{t+1}, s_{t+1})$ in $\mathcal{D}$
            \STATE Sample mini-batch of transitions $(s_j, a_j, r_{j+1}, s_{j+1})$ from $\mathcal{D}$
            \STATE Perform a gradient descent step using targets $y_j$ with respect to the online parameters $\theta$
            \STATE Every $C$ steps, set $\theta' \leftarrow \theta$
            \ENDFOR
            \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

See Algorithm \ref{alg:DQN}.

\end{document}
```

(2) Compile and generate `Test2WORD.pdf`

**Output**

[image: b]

(3) Open `Test2WORD.pdf` using ms-word (I am using word 2013).

The Word document is in the selected font and is fully editable. See the yellow highlight I made.

[image: a]

I found two places that need to be corrected (in red).

[image: c]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works but it distorts the formatting and it becomes extremely hard to fix. is there no other way?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/253889)